# Get WS-Addressing data from CXF service from Java

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have a SOAP based web service running using Apache CXF. I have WS-Addressing configured in my Spring configuration and everything is working fine.  Now, i need to get access to the WS-Addressing values in my web service method...basically i want to insert the ws-addressing messageId in a database.

I do not see anyway to get the WS-Addressing data in my code. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the current CXF message via something like:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage();
```

the AddressingProperties object is stored on there someplace.  For incoming on the server side, I think it would be the key "javax.xml.ws.addressing.context.inbound".